# Adding error page blocks all servlets in tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, custom-error-pages

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse, which uses annotations to map servlets like this:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
    ....
}
```

I also have jsp pages which uses these servlets, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="LoginController">
```

It all work like a char, until I decided to add error pages for errors `404` and `500`. A little search on Google take me to [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Seterrorpageinwebxml.htm) and I find out that I have to modify `web.xml` file to specify error pages. But my project doesn't have a `web.xml` file under `WEB-INF` directory(By the way, I am using Eclipse Indigo as the IDE and Tomcat 7.0.14). So I added one as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>
            404
        </error-code>
        <location>
            /404.html
        </location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>
            500
        </error-code>
        <location>
            /500.html
        </location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

This, introduces a new problem. My servlets are not working anymore! All of my JSPs are working fine. But all requests to my servlets take me to the 404 error page. For example, I can get a login form as JSP's are working fine. But, when I submit my login form, ie., to `LoginController` it brings up 404 error page.

I think it may be solved by using `web.xml` file for servlet mapping instead of `WebServlet` annotation. But is there a way to use `WebServlet` annotation and also provide error pages? I will be happy if `web.xml` can be avoided to show error pages. Also, I don't like to edit any configuration files of tomcat. So, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the doc type, and use the following web-app element declaration:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

The doc type you use declares your web-app as a 2.3 webapp, which doesn't have support for annotations.